# Not able to remove item from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a chat app that adds the messages to an array for each user. It is set to grab the messages at an interval and then print the message to the client window. Once it has done that, it is supposed to remove the message from the array so it will be considered undefined and no longer print the messages. In the code below, I have tried various ways to get this to work with no luck. I have tried to use userMessage.user2.pop() but the console log shows the only item ever popped off is the very first instance of user1, after that it still builds the array. splice() is not working either. I don't understand why this is not working. I have included what I believe to be only the necessary code to find my error:

```
var userMessage = [];
function getMessages() {
    window.setInterval(function(userMessage) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:1337/update/', true)
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var json = '{"messages":' + xhr.responseText + '}';
            newMessages = JSON.parse(json);
            userMessage = newMessages['messages'];
            if (userId == "1") {
                var i = (userMessage.user2.length) -1;
                var message = document.createElement('p');
                var text = document.createTextNode(userMessage.user2[i]);
                console.log(text.textContent);
                if(text.textContent != "undefined"){
                message.appendChild(text);
                chatRoom.appendChild(message);
                message.scrollIntoView(true);
                userMessage.user2.splice(-1,1); 
                }

            }
            if (userId == "2") {
                var i = (userMessage.user1.length)-1;
                var message = document.createElement('p');
                var text = document.createTextNode(userMessage.user1[i]);
                console.log(text);
                if(text.textContent != "undefined"){
                message.appendChild(text);
                chatRoom.appendChild(message);
                message.scrollIntoView(true);
                console.log(userMessage);
                userMessage.user1.splice(-1,1);
                }

            }
        };

    }, 2000);
```

********* back-end code ******

```
var messages = {
    user1 : [],
    user2 : []
};
app.get('/random/:room/:userId/:message', function(req, res) {
    fs.appendFile(room.number.toString(), req.params.message, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error writing messages to file');
        };
        fs.readFile('./' + room.number, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.fileNotFound) {
                    return this.sendErrorMessage('can\'t find the file, you linked it incorrectly');
                }
                console.log('error reading message file');
            };

            if (req.params.userId == 1) {
                messages.user1.push(data);
            } else {
                messages.user2.push(data);
            };
            console.log(messages);
            res.send(data);
            fs.unlink(req.params.room, function(err) {
            });

        });
    });
});

app.get('/update', function(req, res){
    res.send(messages);
    message.user1.pop();
    message.user2.pop();
});
```

Comment: Each time your function runs it make an ajax call that retrieves all the messages again. (Or does it? You don't explain what format the response is in and whether it always includes all elements, but the URL doesn't seem to have any parameters that would limit messages.) In any case **you overwrite `userMessage` each time with the latest response.**

Comment: It does. I am popping the messages off on the back end as well, but only after I give it the res.send. Thank you.

Comment: @nnnnnn - I commented above but I could be wrong. I am going to update the initial post with the back-end code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the wrong variable on the back-end. It should have been messages, I used message. Problem fixed.